# How can I make an IActionFilter available to razor pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages, asp.net-core-identity, action-filter

I have this filter:

```
public class ViewBagFilter : IActionFilter
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext db;

    public ViewBagFilter(ApplicationDbContext _dbContext)
    {
        db = _dbContext;
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var controller = context.Controller as Controller;
        var dataFromDb = {db-query};
        controller.ViewBag.Example = dataFromDb;
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        // do something after the action executes
    }
}
```

... that I am including in `Startup.cs` like this:

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(typeof(ViewBagFilter));
});
```

But when I navigate to any of the Identity razor pages, `ViewBag.Example` does not exist.

How can I make it available to razor pages as well?

This doesn't work:

```
services.AddRazorPages(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(typeof(ViewBagFilter));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filters in Razor Pages are different to MVC. You will need to create a Razor Pages version: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/filters

Note that the dynamic `ViewBag` type is not available in the Razor Pages `PageModel` type.